# Promoted Links list in SPWeb Template

Tags: site, template, report-viewer

My website contains "promoted links" list. I create template from that web site. However, when I create new web site using that template, the URLs in the "promoted links" list isn't updated to reflect this newly created web site, and is static, i.e., pointing to the web site that was used when creating the template.

Is it possible to get the links to be changed automatically at the time of web site creation to point to the newly created site?

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me this question is too unclear to be answered. Please edit the question with a serious grammar-check.

Comment: plz help me i change

Comment: Please add the details of how promoted links list is created with some sample data.  Also, add how you can creating 'new web site using that template'